# How to remove text inside p element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say i have something like this:

```
<p>
 <h1>Coming events</h1>
 <br>
 randomtext
randomtext
randomtext
<h1>Past events</h1>
<br>
randomtext
randomtext
randomtext
</p>
```

I want to remove the h1 containing Past events and every single line of text afther that until the `<p>` closes. I've tried wrapping around a div but that didn't seem to work for me. I'm still in the learning process of jQuery.

So what i expect is the following after the jQuery runs the output would be:

```
<p>
     <h1>Coming events</h1>
     <br>
     randomtext
    randomtext
    randomtext
</p>
```

Comment: You might want to look into reformatting your HTML - heading elements shouldn't be nested within paragraphs. It should precede the paragraph.

Comment: This isn't an option unfortunately the HTML is being parsed from an external website using HTML Agility Pack

Comment: could you add an expected result... it's is kind of unclear what you expect at the moment.

Comment: I've added it to the OP

Comment: The fact that this HTML is invalid doesn't help.

Comment: My browser actually refuses to render those `p` tags.

Comment: jquery can't do anything here you know.. mainly because the html it invalid.

Comment: I've added my own solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way to do that would be to wrap a `div` :

```
<p>
 <div id="sectionA">
    <h1>Coming events</h1>
    <br>
    randomtext
    randomtext
    randomtext
</div>
 <div id="sectionB">
    <h1>Past events</h1>
    <br>
    randomtext
    randomtext
    randomtext
</div>
</p>
```

And then remove it like this : `$('#sectionB').remove();`

But if you can't, you could remove the text like this :

```
var text = $('p').html();
text = text.substr(0,text.indexOf("<h1>Past events</h1>"));
$('p').html(text);
```

Comment: Nice one, I was trying to do it with `afterAll()`, `empty()` and `remove()` but without containers it was impossible.

Comment: Thanks wrapping it was the solution!

Answer (score 0):

```
var $parent = $('p:first').parent();
var text = $parent.html();
$parent.html(text.substr(0, text.indexOf("<h1>Past events</h1>")));
```